# Меню "Конструктора печати документов" работает не так как в пособии по 1С

Tags: 1с

Занимаюсь изучением 1С:Предприятие. Появилась задача создать Печать документа. В пособии представлены данные скрины (1,2).
[image: Начальное окно]
[image: и конечное окно]

Однако у меня другие окна в данном конструкторе и они имеют совсем другой функционал и не делают того, что мне необходимо (3,4).
[image: Начальное окно у меня]
[image: и конечное окно у меня]

Так, у меня нету возможности выставить, чтобы команда относилась к группе "Командная панель формы.Важное", хотя это очень важно в дальнейшей работе.
Пробовал делать такие же действия на другом компьютере с 1С на учебе и там все работало как должно(как в пособии), но я так и не заметил каких либо отличий 1С на учебе от 1С моей.

Помогите решить эту проблему, так как дальнейшее мое изучение сильно стопорится из за данной проблемы.

Answer (score 0):

Может версия разная в книге и у тебя?

Вообще: я никогда не видел такой конструктор, если честно. Могу только посоветовать разобраться вручную, т.к. пользоваться конструкторами на этапе обучения (кроме конструктора запросов) - не очень хорошо